# Is there any difference in meaning between "your" and "sth of yours"

Tags: word-usage

I've been wondering that in sentences like:

> By lifting weight you can toughen those muscles of yours.

Or

> He is a friend of mine.

Why won't we simply say:

> ....your muscles.

Or

> ...my friend.

Do they have a conspicuous difference in meaning? If yes, in which situations should we use the first form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context that you provided, both forms are fully interchangeable.  In my opinion, using the form "of mine" has the benefit of sounding more sophisticated.

> By lifting weights, you can strengthen those muscles of yours.

> By lifting weights, you can strengthen your muscles.

Other situations that the first form is necessary includes "something of mine" (used in sentences linked here: https://ludwig.guru/s/something+of+mine).

Comment: _A friend of mine_ is another way of saying _one of my friends_.